# ajax response: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I send an ajax request with jquery like this:

```
 $.post("ajax/myFile.php", {
    myValue: "test"
    }, function(response) {
      console.log($.parseJSON(response))
    })
```

content of myFile.php

```
myFunctionA();
myFunctionB();

function myFunctionA() {
   echo json_encode(array('error' => 0, 'message' => "Hello World"));
}


function myFunctionB() {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 0, 'message' => "Hello again"));
}
```

my console.log result:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 44 of the JSON data
```

how can I handle this? :/

Comment: It would help if you would include the actual JSON response you are getting. I'm guessing that the two individual `echo`s are each outputting their own JSON, not a cohesive JSON response, so basically 2 JSON back to back, which isn't a valid JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return multiple JSON values from your script. You need to combine them into a single value.

```
echo json_encode([myFunctionA(), myFunctionB()]);

function myFunctionA() {
   return array('error' => 0, 'message' => "Hello World");
}


function myFunctionB() {
    return array('error' => 0, 'message' => "Hello again");
}
```

This will return both results as elements of an array in JavaScript.